# WPF : UserControl DataBinding PropertyChanged does not work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have a Window which uses a UserControl (defined programmatically). My Window uses an Object WindowDatas as DataContext. This object contains an object PJDataContext which defines the Datas for my UserControl (code modularity).

The problem is I can't update the ListView of my UserControl by using PropertyChanged event. However, I know that the binding is correct at initialisation because if my list is not empty, I have something on the screen.

Here is the code : 
UserControl XAML (simplified, don't take account of the Grid.Row property)

```
<UserControl x:Class="DandDAdventures.XAML.Controls.PJView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DandDAdventures.XAML.Controls"
             xmlns:db="clr-namespace:DandDAdventures"
             xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" DataContext="{Binding PJDatas}">
    <Grid>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ListView Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=EventList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                <ListView.Resources>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type db:GroupEvent}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="["/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="]"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.Resources>
            </ListView>
            <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ></GridSplitter>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2"></TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

UserControl DataContext :

```
public class PJDataContext : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public List<GroupEvent> m_groupEvent; //The List

    public PJDataContext()
    {
        m_groupEvent = new List<GroupEvent>();
    }

    public void AddGroupEvent(GroupEvent ge)
    {
        m_groupEvent.Add(new GroupEvent { ID = 25 });
        m_groupEvent.Add(ge);
        this.EventList = m_groupEvent; //Using PropertyChanged
    }

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    public List<GroupEvent> EventList { get => m_groupEvent; set { m_groupEvent = value; OnPropertyChanged("EventList"); } }
}
```

The Window DataContext :

```
public class WindowData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected PJDataContext m_pjDatas;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public WindowData()
    {
        m_pjDatas = new PJDataContext();
    }

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    public String CurrentPJ
    {
        get => m_currentPJ;
        set
        {
           m_currentPJ = value;
        }
     }            
     public PJDataContext PJDatas { get => m_pjDatas; }
}
```

Thank you !

Comment: For collections, or lists I would suggest `ObservableCollection<>` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx, it takes away the pain a bit.

Comment: Either use an ObservableCollection or create a new List instance on each update. `this.EventList = m_groupEvent` will not update the UI when m_groupEvent always holds the same collection instance.

Comment: See, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138992/binding-observablecollection-to-wpf-listbox for an example (note the answer)

Comment: As a note, setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the ItemsSource Binding has no effect. It only applies to Bindings that actually update their source property, i.e. TwoWay or OneWayToSource Bindings.

Comment: Oh, Indeed the ObservableCollection works like a charm. I thought that WPF will see if the List got some changes or reupdate completly its internal states.... wrong guess.. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the line

```
this.EventList = m_groupEvent;
```

in the AddGroupEvent method fires the PropertyChanged event, the event will be ignored by the EventList Binding, because the underlying collection instance hasn't changed.

You should use an `ObservableCollection` for the EventList property, which will also greatly simplify your view model class:

```
public class PJDataContext
{
    public ObservableCollection<GroupEvent> EventList { get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<GroupEvent>();

    public void AddGroupEvent(GroupEvent ge)
    {
        EventList.Add(ge);
    }
}
```

Now even the AddGroupEvent method seems redundant.

Comment: Yeah I know that the references does not change, I thought though that the UI will browse entirely the List again, wrong guess. Thank you !