# Printing list of class objects inside

Tags: c#, list, class, object

How can i print a list with all class objects inside that list?

```
 List<Reader> MyObjectList = new List<Reader>();

 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Reader reader = new Reader();

        reader._surname = Convert.ToString(textBox1.Text);
        reader._id = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
        MyObjectList.Add(reader);

        MessageBox.Show("new reader");
    }
```

I want to print all _surname and _id i add, with button click.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.DataSource = MyObjectList;
    }
```

If i do it like this, my result says: OBJ6.MyObjectList.

PS. OBJ6 - my project name. How can i print all objects inside that class using button click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `List<T>` has not overridden `ToString`, that's why you see it's type name `OBJ6.MyObjectList` as result instead of the desired "all surname and id's".

You can use this:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string whatYouWant = String.Join(
        Environment.NewLine, // change this to the desired delimiter 
        MyObjectList.Select(r => $"{r._surname} {r._id}")); // change format here
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set [ItemTemplate](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-data-binding-item-template/) in your ListBox.

```
<ListBox>
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                        <WrapPanel>
                                                <TextBlock Text="Surname: " />
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding _surname}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                                                <TextBlock Text=", " />
                                                <TextBlock Text="Id: " />
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding _id}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                                        </WrapPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

Also, read about [binding ObservableLists as items source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138992/binding-observablecollection-to-wpf-listbox), so that you don't need a button to refresh the list.