# 2 list boxes, 2 files, 2 folders

Tags: c#, wpf

Im a beginner programmer and im stuck on this project for my internship

Lets say i have hello.txt in folder1 Listbox1 takes it from folder1 and put it in the listbox.

listbox2 does the same thing with folder2 except with a diffrent extension
After for example i have created hello.DOCX i need hello.txt to be removed from listbox1 but not from folder1

i hope this is clear

this is my code to get files from folders

```
private void LBNietGedaan_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\nour\Desktop\Niet gedaan");
    FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.txt");

    foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
    {
        LB1.Items.Add(file.Name);
    }
} 

private void LBGedaan_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //zet files van een folder in de listbox
    DirectoryInfo dinfo = new 
    DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\nour\Desktop\Gedaan");
    FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.DOCX");

    foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
    {
        LB2.Items.Add(file.Name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pseudo, so it might need some adjusting, but basically you can but it in a button click, or place it in your first method after you load the list, adjust the variables to match yours.

```
 List<string> one = new List<string>();
        foreach (String string1 in LB1.Items)
        {
            one.Add(string1);
        }
        List<string> two = new List<string>();
        foreach (String string2 in LB2.Items)
        {
            two.Add(string2);
        }

            foreach (String string1 in one)
        {
            foreach (String string2 in two)
            {
            string    cat1 = string1.Substring(0, string1.Length - 4);
              string  cat2 = string2.Substring(0, string2.Length - 5);
                if (cat1.Equals(cat2))
                {
                   LB1.Items.Remove(string1);
                    // if you want to stop after the first match, break; 
                    // else remove break to find all matches;

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Basically this will search the items in listbox1's Items, and remove any file called "yourtarget.txt". I think should send you in the right direction. If you need more let me know!

Comment: This is kinda what im looking for, if anyone wants to complete his code will be much appreciated. i need to delete remove the file from listbox1 if another file with the same name is created in folder2 but without an extension.

Comment: `note:` when using this, where im making the substring, its counting back from the end of the line, dropping the last four chars (your extension, and the period) to check just the file name... if they are the same, it is removed from list 1

Comment: D does not exist in current context.

Comment: yes yes i adjusted it. those were my placeholders to make sure it worked. d is string 1. i updated the code. should be good now.

Comment: Sorry i think you misunderstood what i typed, i meant that hello.TXT must be removed from listbox1 if listbox2 has hello.DOCX its about the name not about the extension.

Comment: yeah this code removes the extension and just compares the name. if they match it removes it from lb1 regardless of extension

Comment: Well i tried the code nothing happens when listbox1 has a file called hello.TXT
and listbox2 with hello.DOCX.

also if i have hello.TXT in listbox1 aswell as listbox2 it gives me an error
System.InvalidOperationException:

Comment: ahhh,,, farts... so i messed it up,,, .DOCX should be a five in the substring, otherwise its leaving the period. try the code again, and if it dosnt work, post the error for me

Comment: Yes the 5 helped now it recognized but the error remains.
Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

Comment: Also i must add string behind cat  1 and 2 or else it wont recognise it

Comment: yeah thats no problem they need to be declared. i think i got a fix for you.... in the to places whee it says, `.Items` add `ToList()` i updated above

Comment: Substring and tolist are not methods for me

Comment: no not the substring, here:  `foreach(String string1 in LB1.Items.ToList())
  {
    foreach(String string2 in LB2.Items.ToList())
    {`

Comment: ok everything is fine except ToList it says it does recognise it, maybe assembly reffrence?

Comment: k i just got to a computer, so ya know what well make our own lists. lol. the above code does the job tested and working.

Comment: this works!

foreach (String string1 in LB1.Items.Cast<String>().ToList())
            {
                foreach (String string2 in LB2.Items.Cast<String>().ToList())
                {

Comment: glad we could figure it out buddy. if my answer helped at all please accept as answer

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just make a property with an ObservableCollection or so and then bind the listbox to it? Then you can simply clear it and the listbox will be empty again.

[Binding ObservableCollection to WPF ListBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138992/binding-observablecollection-to-wpf-listbox)

Comment: ollabrate please

Comment: @nassermuraat where do you define your listbox and do you have a viewmodel/datacontext or is it all just in one class ?

Comment: All in one class